# Raw HTML content in editing controls

Tags: 2007, wiki, people-picker, internet-explorer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sharepoint/MOSS2007 and the IE9](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/19816/sharepoint-moss2007-and-the-ie9)

After updating the browser to IE9 (I used IE7 before), weird things happen when working on MOSS2007.

When trying to edit content (a wiki entry for example), the textarea for editing shows raw HTML content rather than formatted/parsed text. This also happens for other controls that should render formatted content.

I attached an image showing the phenomenon on a Peoplepicker. [image]

Is this a known problem and is there a way to fix it?

In case it matters: In IE9, Javascript is enabled and compatibility mode doesn't affect the behaviour.

Thanks in advance for any hints.