# Raw HTML content in editing controls using IE9

Tags: 2007, people-picker, internet-explorer, browser-compatibility

After updating the browser to IE9 (I used IE7 before), weird things happen when working on MOSS2007.

When trying to edit content (a wiki entry for example), the textarea for editing shows raw HTML content rather than formatted/parsed text. This also happens for other controls that should render formatted content.

I attached an image showing the phenomenon on a Peoplepicker. [image]

Is this a known problem and is there a way to fix it?

In case it matters: In IE9, Javascript is enabled and compatibility mode doesn't affect the behaviour.

Thanks in advance for any hints.

Comment: Whoa, good to know that platform exists :) Thanks, I'll be flagging this for that reason...

Comment: I'm unable to replicate the problem. I'm using SharePoint 12.0.0.6421, IE 9.0.8112.16421, Win7 default theme, js-enabled, standard settings. I tried QuirksMode and standards mode, settings for IE7, IE8 and IE9. All works (layout is borked, but is works)

Comment: I found that I see normal content when edititing in IE9 if using the 32 bit browser on Windos 7 64 bit OS. I also see similar HTML content if using IE9 64 bit broswser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have experienced and fixed this same problem in the past by installing the February 2010 Cumulative Update:

[Windows SharePoint Services 3.0 Cumulative Update Server Hotfix Package (WSS server-package)](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;978396)

[Office SharePoint Server 2007 Cumulative Update server hotfix package (MOSS server-package)](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;978395)

Further information:

[Rich Finn: Issue With People Picker Showing Strange XML](http://blog.richfinn.net/blog/2010/05/06/IssueWithPeoplePickerShowingStrangeXML.aspx)

Not sure if this will solve your problem, as my issue was on IE7, but it has the same symptoms at least.

Answer (score 1):

IE9 is not an officially supported browser for SharePoint 2007 according to the [Browser Support (Office SharePoint Server)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263526%28office.12%29.aspx) documentation.

You can force the downstream compatibility by adding a META tag to your master page(s). See [Defining Document Compatibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for further detail.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7">
```

As an alternative, you can define the X-UA-Compatible header within IIS as well. [Implementing the META Switch on IIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/cc817572.aspx) provides a step-by-step.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be another feature, that renders the content in a way that causes an error in IE9? This is all I can think of, since Dribbel can't replicate it and I have also previously used the people picker in IE9 without any problems.

So I think you should take a look at which other features you use, and see if any of them are effecting the rendering.